# public dataset in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, public

i need to be able to save and retrieve data in a dataset in multiple places. i didnt want to copy and paste all my code since its pretty large, and i hope my super short version gets the idea across. thanks in advance. i currently have something along the lines of...

```
class program
{

DataSet ds;

static void main(...)
{
getMe(string);
}

public void getMe(string x)
{
ds = new mydataset();
DataRow dr = new ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
//blah blah add x to dr[ column ]
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}

public void readMe()
{
    **need to read dataset here with info added in rows from getMe()

}

}
```

EDIT:

edited DataSet =  ds; to DataSet ds; to reflect my actual code.

if i call getMe(string) in my main, it errors with..."an object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property."

if i change getMe(string x) to public static void getMe(string) the error goes away but shows again for
    ds = new mydataset();

Comment: What is `DataSet = ds;`? That won't compile. If the code in `getMe()` is actually working, then `readMe()` should also work, as `ds` would be in scope for both methods. If you're getting an error, please include it in your question.

Comment: According to given details look like you want a generic class to perform CURD operations. is that what you looking for